# dd is producing a 32 MB random file instead of 1 GB

Tags: script, dd, random-number-generator

I wanted to produce a 1 GB random file, so I used following command.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output bs=1G count=1
```

But instead every time I launch this command I get a 32 MB file:

```
<11:58:40>$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=output bs=1G count=1
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
33554431 bytes (34 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0,288321 s, 116 MB/s
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to great answers in this topic I came with solution that reads 32 chunks 32 MB large which makes 1GB:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output bs=32M count=32
```

Other solution was given that reads 1 GB straight to the memory and then writes to disk. This solution takes a lot of memory so it is not preffered:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output bs=1G count=1 iflag=fullblock
```

Comment: IMHO I don't think there are many valid use cases for `dd` at all. I'd use `head`, `cat` or `rsync` in its place almost always. And your question if one of the reasons why the alternatives are usually safer.

Comment: @Bakuriu - also, if you just want to produce a file full of zeroes (or rather you do not care about what is inside it) use truncate. It is much faster.

Comment: @KonradGajewski FYI truncate tries to make a sparse file (if that matters)

Comment: @Bakuriu `head` cannot do this task without the `-c` option that [isn't in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/head.html). I don't know any version of `cat` which can solve this. `rsync` is a completely nonstandard utility. That is neither here nr there; skimming through its man page, I don't see how it can solve this problem, either.

Comment: Technically, `/dev/urandom` isn't in POSIX either...

Comment: @Xen2050 it might. Thx.

Comment: It's the `bs=1G` part that makes it use a lot of memory. You only *didn't notice* it with /dev/urandom, because of the reasons already explained.

Comment: @grawity that's exactly what I meant in my edit.

Comment: @Kaz Those were only a couple of example. There is no `dd` task that cannot be done better with an other tool. Also, `rsync` isn't POSIX but if you aren't using it you are a moron. Using only POSIX tool transferring files reliably and efficiently between systems cannot be done.

Comment: @Bakuriu Those were a couple of examples indeed: of tools that cannot do most of the things `dd` does.  I believe there are `dd` tasks that cannot be done more *portably* than with `dd`. The command argument language of `dd` is pretty excellent: very easy to remember, and the semantics is transparent.

Comment: Related:  [What’s the difference between dd’s command options bs=1024 count=1 and bs=1 count=1024?](https://superuser.com/q/797664/150988)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`bs`, the buffer size, means the size of a single *read()* call done by dd.

(For example, both `bs=1M count=1` and `bs=1k count=1k` will result in a 1 MiB file, but the first version will do it in a single step, while the second will do it in 1024 small chunks.)

Regular files can be read at nearly any buffer size (as long as that buffer fits in RAM), but devices and "virtual" files often work very close to the individual calls and have some arbitrary restriction of how much data they'll produce per read() call.

For `/dev/urandom`, this limit is defined in *urandom_read()* in [drivers/char/random.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/random.c?id=fc2fd5f0f1aa85925be2322275ee2dc5ac3acdf4#n1882):

```
#define ENTROPY_SHIFT 3

static ssize_t
urandom_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t nbytes, loff_t *ppos)
{
    nbytes = min_t(size_t, nbytes, INT_MAX >> (ENTROPY_SHIFT + 3));
    ...
}
```

This means that every time the function is called, it will clamp the requested size to 33554431 bytes.

By default, unlike most other tools, *dd* will not retry after receiving less data than requested – you get the 32 MiB and that's it. (To make it retry automatically, as in Kamil's answer, you'll need to specify `iflag=fullblock`.)

---

Note also that "the size of a single read()" means that the whole buffer must fit in memory at once, so massive block sizes also correspond to massive memory usage by *dd*.

And it's all pointless because you usually won't gain any performance when going above ~16–32 MiB blocks – syscalls aren't the slow part here, the random number generator is.

So for simplicity, just use `head -c 1G /dev/urandom > output`.

Comment: _"... you usually won't gain any performance when going above ~16–32 MiB blocks"_ - In my experience, you tend not to gain much, or even lose performance above 64-128 **kilo**byte. At that point, you're well in the diminishing returns wrt syscall cost, and cache contention starts to play a role.

Comment: @marcelm I've helped architect high performance systems where IO performance would improve as block size increased to 1-2 MB blocks, and in some cases up to 8 MB or so. Per LUN.  And as filesystems were constructed using multiple parallel LUNs, to get get best performance meant using multiple threads for IO, each doing 1 MB+ blocks. Sustained IO rates were over 1 GB/sec. And those were all spinning disks, so I can see high-performance arrays of SSDs swallowing or generating data faster and faster as the block size grows to 16 or even 32 MB blocks.  Easily.  Maybe even larger.

Comment: I'll explicitly note that `iflag=fullblock` is a GNU extension to [the POSIX `dd` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html).  As the question doesn't specify Linux, I think the use of Linux-specific extensions should probably be explicitly noted lest some future reader trying to solve a similar issue on a non-Linux system be confused.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ah, interesting! I did a quick test with `dd` on my machine, with block sizes from 1k to 512M. Reading from an Intel 750 SSD, optimal performance (about 1300MiB/s) was achieved at 2MiB blocks, roughly matching your results. Larger block sizes neither helped nor hindered. Reading from `/dev/zero`, optimal performance (almost 20GiB/s) was at 64KiB and 128KiB blocks; both smaller _and_ larger blocks decreased performance, roughly matching my previous comment. Bottom line: benchmark for your actual situation. And of course, neither of us benchmarked `/dev/random` :P

Comment: @marcelm Did you try the same tests with `head`? I wonder if always uses the best speed, or if there's some odd cases where `dd` would be faster

Comment: IIRC, coreutils _head_ always used 8k blocks because it wasn't that important. Meanwhile _cp_ actually has some benchmark-related comments in the source code...

Comment: @Xen2050 I did some more quick tests, and it appears `dd` is faster. A quick strace showed that `head` uses 8KiB reads, and two 4KiB writes, which is interesting (GNU coreutils 8.26 on Debian 9.6 / Linux 4.8). `head` speeds are indeed somewhere between `dd bs=4k` and `dd bs=8k`. `head` speeds are down ~40% compared to `dd if=/dev/zero bs=64k` and down ~25% compared to `dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=2M`. The reads from `/dev/zero` are of course more CPU-limited, but for the SSD I/O queing also plays a role. It's a bigger difference than I expected.

Comment: @marcelm That's interesting, thanks. I guess for copying files `cp`'s best (even if dd were slightly faster, there's no attribute copying), or for zero (sparse) files there's truncate or fallocate

Comment: @marcelm, It's my understanding that `head` was specifically recommended for slow devices like `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: L3 cache size on a typical Intel CPU ranges from 4 to 8 MB (on a dual / quad core desktop).  Or up to ~50MB on a huge many-core Xeon.  But L2 size is 256kiB private per core.  If you're doing extra copies of your data in memory (like from using `read` and `write`, which basically ask the kernel to memcpy between user-space and the pagecache), smallish buffers that result in CPU-cache hits can be a good thing.  I don't think it's reasonable to conclude that buffer size has to keep increasing with total throughput. You want it big enough for the kernel/RAID to split as needed.

Comment: @Xen2050 If you want to eliminate Disk IO you can test writing to /dev/shm -- this is ram disk so it will be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 22):

`dd` may read less than `ibs` (note: `bs` specifies both `ibs` and `obs`), unless `iflag=fullblock` is specified. `0+1 records in` indicates that `0` full blocks and `1` partial block was read. However any full or partial block increases the counter.

<strike>I don't know the exact mechanism that makes `dd` read a block that is less than `1G` in this particular case. I guess any block is read to the memory before it's written, so memory management may interfere (but this is only a guess).</strike> Edit: [this concurrent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1388090/432690) explains the mechanism that makes `dd` read a block that is less than `1G` in this particular case.

Anyway, I don't recommend such large `bs`. I would use `bs=1M count=1024`. The most important thing is: without `iflag=fullblock` *any* read attempt may read less than `ibs` (unless `ibs=1`, I think, this is quite inefficient though).

So if you need to read some exact amount of data, use `iflag=fullblock`. Note `iflag` is not required by POSIX, your `dd` may or may not support it. According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618) `ibs=1` is probably the only POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes. Of course if you change `ibs` then you will need to recalculate the `count`. In your case lowering `ibs` to `32M` or less will probably fix the issue, even without `iflag=fullblock`.

In my Kubuntu I would fix your command like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output bs=1M count=1024 iflag=fullblock
```