# Is there any argument against using dd with bs=10G?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, dd, filesystem-corruption

Suppose I have a drive that has a bad superblock (or block) in some random location. It's an enormous drive, 1-8 TB. It won't format to ext3, so I'm writing it full of zeroes so that I can properly format it. `lsblk -f` shows its FSTYPE as an empty string.

Is there any reason not to run the command below?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=10G status=progress of=/dev/bad_disk
```

Comment: What kind of transfer rates do the devices support?

Comment: That’s not going to make anything faster. // Zeroing the device also will not help with formatting it because doing so would overwrite any superblocks anyway. If you want to detect bad blocks, use `badblocks`.

Comment: This example pertains to a Seagate HDD, so the write rate is about 130 MB/s. @DanielB I don't think there are actual bad blocks; the problem, I suspect, was that a superblock was somehow mangled during a failed shutdown process. Under the assumption that the disk is fine, would 10G blocks pre-format ever cause issues?

Comment: With respect to reallocating bad blocks by the harddisk controller, it won't make a difference if you write zeros, or if you write something with meaningful data during formatting. If formatting doesn't work, first have a look at the SMART values and the log to get an idea of what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you cannot interrupt the program while it writes a block and writing 10GB takes significant time. Performance improvement with block size plateaus fairly quickly in my experience, so I would stick to more reasonable sizes (4MB...).

Answer (score 0):

My answer addresses exactly the title:

> Is there any argument against using `dd` with `bs=10G`?

But in your case it's kinda [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). The underlying issue (bad blocks) should be approached with `smartctl` and `badblocks`, not `dd`.

---

#### Memory usage

[This another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1452827/432690) mentions "performance improvement with block size":

> Performance improvement with block size plateaus fairly quickly

True, but it's just a "`bs` near zero" part of the story. In the context of the question we should tell the "`bs` goes to infinity" part.

In the real world the plateau actually collapses for some large `bs`. With `bs=10G` the tool will try to allocate 10 GiB of memory. It may or may not succeed (memory exhausted). Even if it does succeed, there are still issues:

- Other processes may get their allocated memory swapped out to disk.
- The buffer of `dd` may be swapped out to disk. The tool uses it constantly, so the OS would probably swap out other (not recently accessed) data first. Still, if you have 8 GiB RAM and 16 GiB of swap, there's no way to fit `bs=10G` in RAM.
- If memory is needed later, [OOM killer may kick in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136291/108618). Your `dd` may be the first process to kill.

Of course this all depends on how much RAM you have and how much swap space you have, and on what other processes do.

---

#### Hints

My personal preference is to use `bs` of a size that gets transferred in 0.1-1 second; or smaller `bs` if RAM usage may be an issue. This way I can interrupt `dd` almost instantly (this is the gist of the [already mentioned answer](https://superuser.com/a/1452827/432690)). If hardware limitations allowed `dd` to exceed 10 GiB/s and I had more than 40 GiB of free ram, I would consider `bs=10G`. At home I hardly ever go above `bs=64M`.

One usage case where `bs=10G` may be useful is when you want to process *exactly* as much data and you use `count=1` (or e.g. 5 times as much: `count=5`). *However* in practice with large `bs` you may get *less*, unless you use `iflag=fullblock` (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1388089/432690)). Because of memory usage I would recompute to a smaller `bs` anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is more of an XY problem than a question. Thanks for pointing that out!